# Finding Parametric Equation of Curve with some conditions

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization, frenet-frame

Let $S$ be a Sphere (in 3d space ,i.e. $\mathbb{R^3}$) and $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to S$ be a curve that is parameterized by length. For all $t$ , we have $|\gamma''(t)| = k<1$ and $k$ is a constant. We have

$$\gamma(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} (2,1,-1)\\
   \gamma'(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (1,-1,1)$$
and $B(0)$ (Binormal) is parallel to $(1,2,1)$.

Find the parametric equation of $\gamma$, i.e. $\gamma (t) = (f_1(t) , f_2(t) , f_3(t))$.

I found that because $k$ is constant, the curve is maybe a circle. Because it is parameterized by length  $T = \gamma'$ and $N = \gamma ''$ and $B = T \times N$.

By using these, I found that $N(0) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt2} , 0 , \frac{-1}{\sqrt2})$.

But I don't know how to use these to find the actual equation. How should I use these to get the actual circle equation?

Comment: How can we have $\gamma''(t) = k < 1$?  $\gamma''(t)$ is a *vector*; $k$ is a real scalar.  Perhaps you mean $\vert \gamma ''(t) \vert = k$ or something similar?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, it was my typo.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Try proving that the binormal is constant. From that, show that $\gamma$ must lie in a plane. From there, it is easy. I don't know if by "a Sphere", you mean the unit sphere about the origin, but you should solve it for that sphere first, where you can make use of the fact that $\langle \gamma, \gamma \rangle = 1$. Generalizing to any sphere is then also simple.

Comment: @amir na Do you want to know how to prove that the curve is a circle? (Since you wrote 'is maybe a circle' in your post, it seems you are not sure about this.) Or do you just want to find the actual parametrization of the circle? Or do you want help with both?